# Pyenv-virtualenv not loaded into shell properly & .zshrc (SOLVED)

Tags: bash, zsh, pyenv

I am a first-time pyenv user. I have been following [this installation article](https://medium.com/swlh/a-guide-to-python-virtual-environments-8af34aa106ac) on Medium. I must have messed up a step because I get an error. I have gone over and over it again but cannot seem to find it. So maybe someone can help me.

Heads up, I think I might have bombed it because midway I decided to move from bash to .zsh. I provide the errors I get. When I write:

```
% pyenv local venv-project && pyenv activate venv-project
```

The error that pops up is:

```
Failed to activate virtualenv.

Perhaps pyenv-virtualenv has not been loaded into your shell properly.
Please restart current shell and try again.
```

On my home directory I have the following files:

```
-rw-------   1 diego  staff   1786 May 16 14:57 .bash_history
-rw-r--r--   1 diego  staff    544 May 16 15:16 .bash_profile
drwx------  13 diego  staff    416 May 16 14:57 .bash_sessions
drwxr-xr-x   6 diego  staff    192 May 16 17:04 .pyenv
-rw-------   1 diego  staff   1532 May 16 17:24 .zsh_history
-rw-r--r--   1 diego  staff    718 May 16 17:24 .zshrc
```

The .zshrc document did not exist when I installed .zsh, so I created it. At first I read online that I could write `source ~/.bash_profile` to direct the file to .bash_profile but that did not work. So I decided to copy and paste what was on .bash_profile into .zshrc as the complete rookie I am. Anyway, so I did that and it did not work. I decided to change things to look like the screenshot from the article I mention above and ended up with this:

```
# >>> conda initialize >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$('/Users/diego/opt/anaconda3/bin/conda' 'shell.bash' 'hook' 2> /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    \eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/Users/diego/opt/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        CONDA_CHANGEPS1=false conda activate base
    else
        \export PATH="/Users/diego/opt/bin:$PATH"
        #export PATH="/Users/diego/opt/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup

export PYENV_ROOT= "$HOME/.pyenv"
export PATH=$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH"
eval $(pyenv init -)
eval "$(pyenv virtualenv-init -)"
```

I think I just messed it up and truly do not know where to go from here. Now every time I open the terminal it says:

```
/.zshrc:export:18: not valid in this context: /Users/diego/.pyenv
```

Any suggestions or explanations on the different places where I went wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have a stray space in your attempt to assign a value to `PYENV_ROOT`. `zsh` thinks you are trying to export the name `/Users/diego/.pyenv` as a result.

Comment: Thanks for this chepner. I did not know that a space would mean a different thing! I have also seen that on PATH=$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH" I only have a set of " at the end, I added them before "$PYENV (is this correct)? Then it told me that there was a "parse error near `()'" I added " " on "$(pyenv init -). It seems to work fine, but did I do something that will generate problems in the future by changing these?

Comment: Quotes need to be matched. Drop the stray quote, which right now starts an argument that includes the following newline and the string `eval` on the next line, ending with the first quote in following line.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to explain this to me, chepner. Have a good day.